# sqlite unable do delete file because "it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I've migrated a app netcore 3 to netcore8 and now I facing this error when I try to File.Delete a sqlfile that was create with EF.

I've tried to use these guys:

```
if(somethingIsNotAsIvePlanned){
    db.Context.Database.GetDbConnection().Close();
    sqlite.Context.Dispose();
    GC.Collect();
    File.Delete(sqlLiteFilePath);
}
```

But I'm facing the error below:
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\tmp.db3' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Given all is closed and disposed as expected, you still need to give the FileSystem some time. It may not update the file status immediately (enough).

Comment: I made it up just as a sample to this post. In my tests I did a while with trycatch inside with 5 tries where in the catch I had a sleep of 5sec with gc.collect together 